# C#: App with NotifyIcon in SystemTray -> unable to add context menu

Tags: c#, forms, contextmenu

I am just starting with C# (Windows 10/MS Studio 2019). The app should have **no** form and an only an icon in the system tray with a context menue:

I used the following code the icon & it works:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace demo
{
    static class Program
    {
    [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            NotifyIcon notifyIcon1 = new NotifyIcon();

            notifyIcon1.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + @"\icon.ico");
            notifyIcon1.Text = "Demo";
            notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
            Application.Run();
         }
    }
}
```

But I am unable to add a context menue to the icon. Code samples since

```
ContextMenu contextMenu1 = new ContextMenu();
```

fails. Error: **"type or namespacename ContextMenue not available"**.

I thought is is included in **"System.Windows.Forms"**...

Any ideas/solution?

Many thanks
Andreas

Comment: Is your windows forms project targeting net core 3.1 or later (.net 5)? The documentation for contextmenu states it’s not available in such a case

Comment: Use [`ContextMenuStrip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip?view=net-5.0).